# find the eigenmodes of a circular membrane (resolution of the wave equation with limit condition)

Tags: python

I'd like to write a Python's code, that finds and represents in 3D the eigenmodes of a vibrating circular membrane, that is fixed and excited in its middle (like the Chladni's figures). How can I do it? (I'm a beginner) What kind of package can I use for it? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: there are two ways, first use a differential equation solver to simulate the evolution of the membrane, or you can just take the solved equation and just plot in 3D the excitation modes.

Comment: I tried to find a solver, but my equation is with t but also with x and y. I don't find some programm, that do it..

Answer (score 0):

Looking into Numpy documentation would be a good start. It contains a complete and quite efficient linear algebra module.

See for yourself : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of that work done in this question, that I asked and solved time ago. [forcing term at the center](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43455/does-anyone-know-how-to-add-a-forcing-term-at-the-center-of-a-cicular-membrane)

I also figured out how to add the free boundary condition that is needed for the Chaldni Figure. Note that for having a better solution you need to use a plate, not a membrane. I don't know hoe to do that in a circular membrane, but this paper shows the way for a plate. [paper](https://uwaterloo.ca/computational-mathematics/sites/ca.computational-mathematics/files/uploads/files/linqi_shao_report_pdf.pdf)

In this code, I also allow the user to select the forcing term

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import jn_zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#%% Parameters
Nr = 50
N_phi = 50
N_steps = 10000
radius =1
c = 4
dphi = 2*np.pi/N_phi
dr = radius/Nr
dt = 0.001
CFL=c*dt*(1/dr+1/dphi)
print(CFL)



#%% Initial conditions
r = np.linspace(0, radius, Nr)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N_phi)
R, phi = np.meshgrid(r, phi)
X = R*np.cos(phi)
Y = R*np.sin(phi)

#%% Tipos de forzantes
sigma=1
def forzante(x,tipo):
    if tipo==1:
        return np.sin(x)
    if tipo==2:
        if x == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return np.sin(x) / x
    if tipo==3:
        return np.exp(-x**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
    if tipo==4:
        return ((x**2 - sigma**2) / sigma**4) * np.exp(-x**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

#%% Selecciión de modo y tipo de forzante
m=1
n=1
frec= jn_zeros(m, n)[n-1]*c/radius

print("la frecuencia es",frec,"modo",m,n)

tipo=1
frec=120
b=2
#%% Stepping
u = np.zeros((N_steps, Nr, N_phi))
k1 = (c*dt)**2/dr**2
for t in range(0, N_steps-1):
    for i in range(0, Nr):
        for j in range(-1, N_phi-1):
            ri = max(r[i], 0.5*dr)  # To avoid the singularity at r=0
            k2 = (c*dt)**2/(2*ri*dr)
            k3 = (c*dt)**2/(dphi*ri)**2
            if i==Nr-1:
                #print("entre",i,j)
                u[t+1, i, j]=1/(1+b*dt/2)*(2*u[t, i, j] - u[t-1, i, j]\
                +k1*( 2*u[t,i-1,j] -2*u[t,i,j] ) \
                +k3*(u[t, i, j+1] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i, j-1]) \
                +b*dt/2*(u[t-1,i,j]) )
            else:
                u[t+1, i, j] = 1/(1+b*dt/2)*(2*u[t, i, j] - u[t-1, i, j] \
                + k1*(u[t, i+1, j] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i-1, j])\
                + k2*(u[t, i+1, j] - u[t, i-1, j])\
                + k3*(u[t, i, j+1] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i, j-1])\
                +b*dt/2*(u[t-1,i,j]))#damping term
                if i in range (0,2):
                    u[t+1,i,j]=u[t+1,i,j]+1/5*forzante(frec*dt*t, tipo)
                #if i==24 and j==0:
                    #u[t+1,i,j]=u[t+1,i,j]+1/5*np.sin(frec*dt*t)
             

#%% Plot 11
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Z = u[9800]  # Or choose another time step to visualize # Crece hasta 150 maximo en 610
# Recien en 900 empieza a cambiar el sentido
ax.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title("Modo {}, {}".format(m, n))
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
#ax.view_init(azim=70, elev=13)
plt.show()
```